# Cannot convert value of type to expected argument type NSURLSessionDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, types

I understand it should be very simple but I am a novice with Swift and cannot get what is wrong here:

```
public class API : NSObject, NSURLSessionDelegate{

    public class func sendHttpRequestNew(urlPath: String, params: AnyObject, method: String)-> Int {
        var delegate = self
        let txtUserName = "admin"
        let txtPassword = "test1234"
        let PasswordString = "\(txtUserName):\(txtPassword)"
        let PasswordData = PasswordString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        let base64EncodedCredential = PasswordData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
        let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!

        let request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        request.setValue("Basic \(base64EncodedCredential)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.HTTPMethod = method
        if method == "POST" || method == "PUT" {
            request.HTTPBody = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: [])
        }
        let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier("unique")
        let authString = "Basic \(base64EncodedCredential)"
        config.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization" : authString]
        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)

        let downloadTask = session.downloadTaskWithRequest(request)
        downloadTask.resume()
    }
}
```

I got an error on this line with `self`:
`let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)`

Cannot convert value of type 'API.type' to expected argument type NSURLSessionDelegate

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The issue here is the method is declared with `class`, making it a [`type method`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH15-ID234). When you refer to `self` inside this method, you are referring to the class `API` itself, and hence the error.

`public class API : NSObject, NSURLSessionDelegate`

is declaring API to be a subclass of NSObject, which conforms to NSURLSessionDelegate.

When assigning a delegate to the URL session, the object assigned has to be an ***instance*** of API.
There are two ways to remedy this:

1. Make sendHttpRequest() a normal method by getting rid of the `class` prefix, or,
2. Create the session using `let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config, delegate: API(), delegateQueue: nil)`, which creates an instance of API and passes that as the delegate.

In my opinion, the first option is better. That way you can keep an instance of `API` around somewhere else and make your networking calls to it like that.

Comment: If I use first option, when I call function, I cannot pass parameters to this function because call should look like: `API.sendHttpRequestNew(self : API)`

Comment: You need to create an object of API by doing something like `let api = API()`, and then calling the method on the `api` object: api.sendHttpRequestNew(...)